# Armazenar operador aritmético em variável

Tags: php, operadores

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$value1 = 10;
$value2 = $value1 + 10; // $value2 == 20
```

Preciso que o operador `+` seja variável, ou seja, no meu caso preciso que seja `+` ou `-`.

Tentei o óbvio mas já certo que não funcionaria, abaixo segue o código:

```
$operator = "+";
$value1 = 10;
$value2 = $value1 . $operator . 10;
```

É possível realizar algo próximo ao que estou tentando fazer?

**Importante:** A variável `$operator` sempre receberá o valor `+` ou `-` em formato de `string`.

Comment: Alguma razão especial para quereres fazer isto ?

Comment: Na verdade não. É que me deparei já com esta situação algumas vezes, e sempre utilizei condição para realizar esta tarefa. Gostaria de saber se haveria algo próximo do formato que citei na pergunta.

Comment: isso tem cheiro de coisa desnecessária.. rsrs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Existem várias formas de fazer isto, mas a melhor é não inventar, é fazer o óbvio utilizando uma comparação. Exemplo:

```
$operator = "+";
$value1 = 10;
switch ($operator) {
    case "+":
        $value2 = $value1 + 10;
        break;
    case "-":
        $value2 = $value1 - 10;
        break;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/Calculator.php).

Tem outros exemplos interessantes em outras respostas.

Comment: É isso mesmo, mas, sem uma condição para verificar a string `$operator` será que seria possível?

Comment: É possível, usando eval.

Comment: @ThyagoThySofT Não seria sem fazer uma enorme gambiarra e tornar o código inseguro. Existem outras formas de escrever isto, mas no fundo todas vão usar uma comparação.

Comment: @RafaelMenaBarreto nem cogite isto.

Comment: @RafaelMenaBarreto don't do this.

Comment: Eu não faço mesmo, só respondi a pergunta.

Comment: Seria possível implementar sem a necessidade de "testar" a string `$operator`, utilizando padrões de projeto.
Exemplo: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)#Encapsulation ]

Comment: @LeonardoLeal é possível, mas provavelmente seria um abuso.

Answer (score 7):

Conintuo a não entender o porquê, mas podes também usar este método, para opções em linha:

```
<?php

$operar = [
    '+' => function($a, $b) { return $a + $b; },
    '%' => function($a, $b) { return $a % $b; },
    '*' => function($a, $b) { return $a * $b; },
    '-' => function($a, $b) { return $a - $b; }
];

$sinal = '+';

print $operar[$sinal](10,10); # (int) 20
print $operar['+'](10,10); # (int) 20

?>
```

Podes ainda utilizar a estrutura de controle **switch** como feito na outra resposta, seja como for, são ambas funcionais.

Comment: Em algumas circunstâncias em usaria desta forma.

Comment: O mais estranho é que nunca fui forçado nenhuma das formas, em tanto tempo de programação.

Answer (score 3):

Eu implementaria da seguinte forma :

```
$value1 = 10;
$operador = '+';
$value2 = ($operador === '+') ? 10 : -10;

$value2 = $value1 + $value2;
```

ou

```
$value1 = 10;
$value2 = 10;
$operador = '+';
if($operador == '-'){
    $value2 *= -1;
}

$value2 = $value1 + $value2;
```

Comment: Eu faria como no primeiro também se for algo simples e fixo sempre. Eu dei o `switch` para poder expandir.

Comment: @bigown De fato se começar a trabalhar com todos os operadores é melhor fazer por `switch`.

Comment: Realmente é limitado a `+` e `-`

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma de implementar é utilizando [BC Math Funções](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.bc.php) e [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.call-user-func.php), exemplo:

```
/*
* bcadd = adição
* bcsub = subtração
* bcmul = multiplicação
* bcdiv = divisão
*/
$operador = 'add';
$val1 = 10;
$val2 = 10;
$result = call_user_func('bc'.$operador,$val1,$val2);
```

**[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/HC5mx5)**

Answer (score 0):

Você também poderia fazer da seguinte forma usando orientação a objetos, onde todo a complexidade fica por responsábilidade da classe Calculator resolver, assim fazendo com que sua utilização fica bem mais fácil, tanto quando a manutenção futura do código.

```
<?php

class Calculator {

  private $operator;
  private $result;

  public function __construct($value1)
  {
    $this->result = $value1;
  }

  public function calculate($operator, $value1)
  {

    switch ($operator) {
      case '+':
        $this->result += $value1;
        break;
      case '-':
        $this->result -= $value1;
        break;
      case '/':
        $this->result /= $value1;
        break;
      case '*':
        $this->result *= $value1;
        break;
      case '%':
        $this->result %= $value1;
        break;
    }

    return $this;

  }

  public function getResult()
  {
    return $this->result;
  }

}
```

Teste de utilização da classe Calcular:

```
<?php

require_once 'Calculator.php';

$calc = new Calculator(10);
echo $calc->calculate('+', 10)
->calculate('+', 10)
->getResult();//30

echo '<br>';
$calc1 = new Calculator(100);
echo $calc1->calculate('-', 10)->getResult();//90

echo '<br>';

$calc2 = new Calculator(2);
echo $calc2->calculate('*', 2)
->calculate('*', 2)
->getResult();//8
```

Comment: Se for um construtor para realizar cálculos simples de adição e soma, e outros, é dispensável o uso de uma classe, uma função normal faria o mesmo.

Comment: Uma função normal faria o mesmo com encadeamento de metodos?

Comment: É esse o ponto, não seria necessário encadear métodos, apenas 1 função faria tudo.

Comment: Sim, se for desenvolver de forma estruturada uma função simples pode resolver, mas em um sistema orientada objetos com arquitetura MVC por exemplo, não seria uma boa prática, que não vem ao caso aqui.